# Problema com model laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Bom estou tendo um problema com meu model, realmente não sei o que esta acontecendo, estou criando um CRUD de embalagens onde eu adiciono tudo dinamicamente com o laravel pelos requests na assinatura da função.

Ao tentar editar/visualizar/deletar meu controller retorna vazio, como se eu estive-se acessando um model vazio. Não da nenhum erro so voltando vazio. Para testar eu listei todas as embalagens ja cadastradas e funcionou perfeitamente.

Meus arquivos estão estruturados da seguinte maneira:

### EMBALAGEM CONTROLLER

```
public function index(){
    $embalagens =  Embalagem::all();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $embalagens;
    }else{
        return view('Embalagem.listEmbalagem', compact('embalagens'));
    }
}

public function create(){
    $embalagem = new Embalagem();
    return view('Embalagem.cadEmbalagem', compact('embalagem'));
}

public function store(EmbalagemRequest $resquest){
    $embalagem = Embalagem::create($resquest->all());
    $embalagens = Embalagem::all();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $embalagem;
    }else{
        return view('Embalagem.listEmbalagem', compact('embalagens'));
    }
}

public function show(Embalagem $embalagem){
    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $embalagem;
    }else{
        return view('Embalagem.showEmbalagem', compact('embalagem'));
    }
}

public function edit(Embalagem $embalagem){
    return view('Embalagem.editEmbalagem', compact('embalagem'));
}

public function update(EmbalagemRequest $request, Embalagem $embalagem){
    $embalagem->update($request->all());
    $embalagens = Embalagem::all();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $embalagem;
    }else{
        return view('Embalagem.listEmbalagem', compact('embalagens'));
    }
}

public function destroy(Embalagem $embalagem){
    $deleted = $embalagem->delete();
    $embalagens = Embalagem::all();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return (string) $deleted;
    }else{
        return view('Embalagem.listEmbalagem', compact('embalagens'));
    }
}
```

### EMBALAGEM MODEL

```
namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Embalagem extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['NmEmbalagem', 'DscEmbalagem', 'UnitEmbalagem'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'CdEmbalagem';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

### EMBALAGEM REQUEST

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'NmEmbalagem' => 'required|min:1',
        'DscEmbalagem' => 'required|min:5'
    ];
}
```

### MINHAS ROTAS

```
Route::singularResourceParameters();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function (){
   Route::resource('clientes', 'ClienteController');
   Route::resource('categorias', 'CategoriaController');
   Route::resource('embalagens', 'EmbalagemController');
});

|        | POST      | embalagens                  | embalagens.store   | App\Http\Controllers\EmbalagemController@store          | web,web    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | embalagens                  | embalagens.index   | App\Http\Controllers\EmbalagemController@index          | web,web    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | embalagens/create           | embalagens.create  | App\Http\Controllers\EmbalagemController@create         | web,web    |
|        | PUT|PATCH | embalagens/{embalagen}      | embalagens.update  | App\Http\Controllers\EmbalagemController@update         | web,web    |
|        | DELETE    | embalagens/{embalagen}      | embalagens.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\EmbalagemController@destroy        | web,web    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | embalagens/{embalagen}      | embalagens.show    | App\Http\Controllers\EmbalagemController@show           | web,web    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | embalagens/{embalagen}/edit | embalagens.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\EmbalagemController@edit           | web,web    |
```

### MINHA MIGRATION

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('embalagems', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('CdEmbalagem');
        $table->string('NmEmbalagem');
        $table->string('DscEmbalagem');
        $table->string('UnitEmbalagem');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

> O que pode ser que esta acontecendo ? Esta faltando algo que não consigo ver ?

Comment: O que retorna um `dd()` na variável `$embalagens` no seu index? Já rodou as migrations e populou o banco ?

Comment: Sim meu banco ja esta populado, meu problema esta acontecendo no edit/show/destroy

Comment: @RenanRodrigues a sua implementação e nome de métodos e parâmetros para Controller do tipo resource estão errado, dá uma olhada na minha resposta como seria !!! qualquer duvida! Tem que seguir a mesma normativa podendo até acrescentar outros parâmetros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando `Controller` do tipo `resource` seria assim os *métodos* e *parâmetros*:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class GeralController extends Controller
{        
    public function index()
    {
    }            

    public function create()
    {
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
    }
}
```

agora é implementar dessa forma e utilizar as [rotas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers).

Tabela de Rotas de um `Controller` do tipo `resource`:

```
|Verb         |          URI           |   Action     |  Route Name    |
|======================================================================|
|GET          |/geral                  |   index      | geral.index    |
|GET          |/geral/create           |   create     | geral.create   |
|POST         |/geral                  |   store      | geral.store    |
|GET          |/geral/{geral}          |   show       | geral.show     |
|GET          |/geral/{geral}/edit     |   edit       | geral.edit     |
|PUT/PATCH    |/geral/{geral}          |   update     | geral.update   | 
|DELETE       |/geral/{geral}          |   destroy    | geral.destroy  |
```

Referência:

- [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers)

Método exemplo como deveria ficar:

**Edit:**

```
public function edit($id, Embalagem $emb)
{
    $embalagem = $emb->find($id); // ou Embalagem::find($id);
    return view('Embalagem.editEmbalagem', compact('embalagem'));
}
```

---

**Show:**

```
public function show($id, Embalagem $emb)
{
    $embalagem = $emb->find($id); // ou Embalagem::find($id);
    if(Request::wantsJson())
    {
        return $embalagem;
    }
    else
    {
        return view('Embalagem.showEmbalagem', compact('embalagem'));
    }
}
```

---

***Destroy:***

```
public function destroy($id, Embalagem $emb)
{
    if(Request::wantsJson())
    {
        $model = $emb->find($id);
        return (string) $model->delete();
    }
    else
    {
        $embalagens = $emb->all();
        return view('Embalagem.listEmbalagem', compact('embalagens'));
    }
}
```

***Update:***

```
public function update(EmbalagemRequest $request, Embalagem $emb, $id)
{
    $embalagem = $emb->find($id);
    $embalagem->fill($request->all());
    $embalagem->save();

    if(Request::wantsJson())
    {
        return $embalagem;
    }
    else
    {
        $embalagens = Embalagem::all();
        return view('Embalagem.listEmbalagem', compact('embalagens'));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Brother, estou utilizando model para instanciar meus objetos, por isto estou passando aqueles parametros

Comment: Eu sei, eu sou desenvolvedor com Laravel, mas, observe o seu edit por exemplo faça a comparação, você até pode instânciar fazer injeção sem problemas mas, o corpo do método também está errado.Vou colocar o edit para você entender, ok

Comment: Qual seria sua solução para meu caso, como ficaria ?

Comment: Cara você é o melhor kkkkk, so não entendo o porque de eu fazer o mesmo em categorias e funcionar

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora, acredito que consiga terminar e tente ver como é a nomenclatura básica ... vlw!

Comment: no caso do update como ficaria ?

Comment: Eu acho que é quase isso que eu postei, dá uma olhada! fiquei em duvida do que você está fazendo nesse método depois de salvar!